# what am I missing to output a reverse triangle

Tags: java

Here is what I have so far. When I run the code I am getting the correct number of letters however It is outputting in a straight line instead of a reverse triangle pattern.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner f = new Scanner(new File("labA21.dat"));
        while (f.hasNext()) {
            triangleTwo(f.nextInt(), String.format(""+ f.next().charAt(0)));
        }
    }

    /**
      Description: output a reverse triangle given a number of rows and a letter
      @param r a number of rows
      @param let a letter that we want to output
    */
    public static void triangleTwo(int r, String let) {

        for (int a=r;a>=1;a==) {
            for (int b=1;b<=a;b++)
                System.out.println(let);
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

What I'm getting:

> A
>   A
>   A
>
> A
>   A
>
> A

What I'm supposed to get:

> AAA
>   AA
>   A

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: Edit question and show what you're actually getting, and what you're expecting.

Comment: print =/= println

Comment: When Andreas asked you to add the current/expected output, his first comment was still valid: put text, not images

Comment: I've edited your question for you — now people would be able to _copy your code_ and _paste it_ into their own editor or IDE, compile it, run it, and change it to help answer your question. _**Never**_ put _pictures of code_ in a question — put _actual code_.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got the right code.

The problem is the method you call to print the characters.

`System.out.println(String)` prints a String then a line break. This is what you want to do at the end of each rows. But not between each characters.

To print a String without including a line break at the end, use `System.out.print(String)`.

Check the java [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) or the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-) for more details.

```
public static void triangleTwo(int r, String let) {
    for (int a=r; a>=1; a--) {
        for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {
            System.out.print(let); // no line break between char of the same row
        }
        System.out.println(); // line break for the end of the row
    }
    System.out.println(); // another line break, this is optional
}
```

**Side note**: Next time you post a question on SO, post the code, the current output, and the expected ouput as text. Text is more persistant than images and can be copy/paste easily by anyone without losing time rewriting the whole code.